# transfer file from Unix to a writeable Windows share, if I don't have direct login rights to the latter

Tags: windows, active-directory, linux-networking, unix, network-share

I'm an sa on Unix side, and there is a writeable Windows share, which I can access from my desktop using an AD service account.

How can I batch a file transfer from Unix over to that mount (it's not Samba-connected from Unix).

Ports 22,21,23,80,443 are not open on the Windows host.
I was thinking maybe Java connect using native Windows network protocols?

Using a service AD account on both systems. Can install stuff on Unix, can not remote to Windows.

What can I explore as possible solutions?

Comment: The obvious answer is to mount the windows share using SMB. Why can't you do that?

Comment: Smb v2 protocol was the answer, and TU for an idea.

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately was the winning path

File: /etc/samba/smb.conf

Entries:

```
client min protocol = SMB2
min protocol = SMB2
```

Call:

```
smbclient -U $username '//$servername/$share' -D "$directory" -c "ls"
```